# Images sometimes don't load in my web application

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat

In my Java web application, the images sometimes fail to appear, instead showing the "broken link" red X symbol. Looking at the Network tab in Chrome's developer tools, I can see that the images are being loaded with a status code of 200 (OK) and the correct content type header. There does not appear to be a content length header, if that matters.

I have not been able to reproduce the issue when I run the application locally from my IDE; it only seems to happen when I run it on the server. My first thought was that it might have something to do with IE's Compatibility View, but the same thing happens whether Compatibility View is on or off, and it also happens in Chrome. I also tried changing some of IE's security settings, since the app is in the Local Intranet Zone when I run it locally, while it is in Trusted Sites when it I run it on the server. That didn't help.

I don't think there is anything unusual about the img tags in the JSP. I am using an older DOCTYPE because it prevents IE 8 from putting a border around the page, and I need to support IE 8. The border is undesirable, but if changing the DOCTYPE would fix the problem, it would be worth it. I realize that the older DOCTYPE puts IE into quirks mode, but changing it to `<!DOCTYPE html>` didn't seem to help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head> ... </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img class="loginButton" width="100" height="28" alt="Log In" title="Log In" src="images/login.png"/>
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

If I reload the page, some of the images will reappear, while others will disappear. I typically have to reload the page 4 or 5 times before all the images will appear. Clearing cache and/or cookies didn't seem to help.

There are not a lot of images, typically only 6 or 7 on a page, and they are no bigger than 4kb in size. Some images are GIFs while others are PNGs; both types have the same problem. I am running Tomcat 7 on Java 1.6 both locally and on the server.

Another piece of information, although I'm not sure how it fits into the puzzle: I looked in the folder where IE stores its cached files, and I noticed that the file for one of the images that was not being displayed had a file size of 0. I deleted the file, reloaded the page, and the image appeared. Then I reloaded the page a couple of times until the image disappeared, and looked in the cache directory. Once again, the image file had a size of zero. I'm not sure why that would happen.

I have looked around and seen similar questions, but so far no solution. I've tried to supply all the information that I thought would be relevant, but let me know if there is anything else that might be important. Thanks for your help.